# Issue with building an animation for a TextView in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation, textview

I have an Android application which populates a `ListView`. When user clicks on any element of it, a `TextView` appears at the bottom of the clicked element to show some information about the element. I'm using `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE` to make this `TextView` appear and disappear with no animation, this works fine and I achieved to do so.

I want that the TextView appears like in this flash animation:
[TextView appearing animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5edgw50o2dok8np/news_deploy.swf)

Can I use XML animations to make something like that??? Or are there any libraries, add-ins or plugins to achieve an animation like that????

Regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are not specific about what type of animations and just want it to look pretty,you can try this
android:animateLayoutTransitions=true

add this to your listview layout and see if these meet your tase

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(250);
set.addAnimation(animation);

animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
animation.setDuration(150);
set.addAnimation(animation);
TextView txtXyz = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtxyz);
txtXyz.setAnimation(animation);
```

Hope you like this transitions!! All the best

Comment: You set the object `animation` to your `TextView txtXyz`. What do the `set` object stands for if you didn't use it???

Comment: set is used to add animation in Animation set
    `set.addAnimation(animation);`

Comment: Yes, you're creating an `AnimationSet` for adding to it the two animations you're creating (`AlphaAnimation` and `TranslateAnimation`). But shouldn't the last line be:
`txtXyz.setAnimation(set)` instead?